# What does this ? operator in C++ do?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

Consider this function

```
template<class T> inline bool cx(T &a, T b) {return a < b ? a = b, 1 : 0;}
```

Can anyone explain what exactly this is doing? It seems different from the typical `condition ? true : false` format.

Comment: It *is* the typical `condition ? true : false`

Comment: Then I am not understanding which piece is what, because what I see is `condition ? condition, true: false`

Comment: Then you should ask what `a = b, 1 ` means. Or how the full thing is parsed, taking into account operator precedence. But it is a standard conditional expression. The code does seem to be written to confuse though.

Comment: Hint: `a = b` isn't a condition, it's an assignment.

Comment: This question cries out for two dupes:  What is the ternary ?: operator, and What is the comma operator.

Comment: @NathanOliver Nope, OP understands the "typical" `?` usage, but is confused by the `a = b, 1` part.

Comment: @PaulRoub Then shouldn't this what is the `,` for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We could make it more clear like so:

```
return a < b ? (a = b, 1) : 0;
```

The parenthesized bit means "assign `b` to `a`, then use `1` as our value".

[Comma-separated lists of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work) in C and C++ generally mean "evaluate all of these, but use the last one as the expression's value".

Comment: I wasn't aware you could combine statements with commas like this in C++ (I always assumed things needed to be separated by semicolons).

Comment: @ArukaJ Those are mainly expressions. The statement is `return <expression>;`.

Comment: @ArukaJ You can't combine _statements_ with commas, only _expressions_.

Answer (score 4):

This combination is a little tricky, because it combines a [*comma operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) with the conditional expression. It parses as follows:

- `a < b` is the condition,
- `a = b, 1` is the "when true" expression
- `0` is the "when false" expression

The result of the comma operator is its last component, i.e. `1`. The goal of employing the comma operator in the first place is to cause the *side effect* of assigning `b` to `a`.

Answer (score 3):

The `,` operator just evaluates all the expressions, left to right, and evaluates to the value of the rightmost expression.

Your code is the same as...

```
if (a < b)
{
  a = b;
  return 1;
}
else
{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... and won't compile.

Comment: @juanchopanza This code is equivalent to `return a < b ? a = b, 1 : 0;`

Comment: @QuestionC Fair enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute several expression using `,`

In this case if a < b, then assign b to a and return 1. According C++ grammar:

```
conditional-expression:  
    logical-or-expression
|   logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

where

```
expression:  
    assignment-expression
|   expression , assignment-expression

assignment-expression:   
    conditional-expression
|   logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
|   throw-expression
```

Answer (score 1):

Read it as:

```
if ( a < b )
{
    a = b;
    return ( 1 );
}
else
{
    return ( 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`a < b ? a = b, 1 : 0` is parsed as `(a < b) ? (a = b, 1) : 0`, a normal conditional operator.  When `a < b` is true, `a = b, 1` is evaluated by assigning `b` to `a` and then "returning" 1.  The net effect of `cx(a,b)` is thus to assign the larger value to `a` and to return 1 if `a` changed, 0 otherwise.